# How to randomize the color of some rectangles

Tags: random, colors, javafx

i'm making a memory game for a school project, and it's working very well, so everything is working the way it should, but there is one problem. I don't know how to let the colors of the cards, the rectangles randomize each time the game is played.

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

var rectangle1: Rectangle;
var rectangle2: Rectangle;
var rectangle3: Rectangle;
var rectangle4: Rectangle;
var rectangle5: Rectangle;
var rectangle6: Rectangle;
var rectangle7: Rectangle;
var rectangle8: Rectangle;
var rectangle9: Rectangle;
var rectangle10: Rectangle;
var rectangle11: Rectangle;
var rectangle12: Rectangle;
var rectangle13: Rectangle;
var rectangle14: Rectangle;
var rectangle15: Rectangle;
var rectangle16: Rectangle;
var kaarten = ["","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red",];
var kaartzichtbaar = [true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true];
var gekozenkaart = [0,0,0];
var tekst = "beginnen maar";
var aantalclicks = 0;
var kaartkeuze = ["",""];
var scene: Scene;
var button: Button;
var score = 0;

function KaartControle (){
    if (aantalclicks == 2){
        if(kaartkeuze [0] == kaartkeuze[1]){
            tekst = "goed bezig!";
            kaartzichtbaar[gekozenkaart[0]]=false;
            kaartzichtbaar[gekozenkaart[1]]=false;
            aantalclicks = 0;
            score++;
        }
    }
    else if (aantalclicks == 3) {
        tekst = "jammer!";
        kaarten[gekozenkaart[0]]="red";
        kaarten[gekozenkaart[1]]="red";
        kaarten[gekozenkaart[2]]="red";
        aantalclicks = 0;
        score--;
    }
    if (score==8) {
    tekst="Hoera!! Het spel is voltooid";
    }
}

Stage {
    title: "Memory"
    scene: Scene {
        width: 500
        height: 300
        content: [
            Text {
                font: Font {
                    size: 16
                }
                x: 10
                y: 30
                content: bind tekst;
            }
            Text {
                font: Font {
                    size: 16
                }
                x: 250
                y: 30
                content: bind score.toString();
            }
            button = Button {
                translateX: 300
                translateY: 150
                text: "reset"
                visible: true
                action: function() {
                    kaartzichtbaar = [true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true];
                    kaarten = ["","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red",];
                    aantalclicks = 0;
                    score = 0;
                    tekst = "beginnen maar"
                }
            }
            //Kaart 1
            rectangle1 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[1]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[1])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[1] == "red"){
                        kaarten[1] = "green";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="1";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 1;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 2
            rectangle2 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[2]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[2])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[2] == "red"){
                        kaarten[2] = "green";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="1";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 2;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 3
            rectangle3 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[3]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[3])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[3] == "red"){
                        kaarten[3] = "cyan";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="2";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 3;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 4
            rectangle4 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[4]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 10
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[4])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[4] == "red"){
                        kaarten[4] = "cyan";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="2";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 4;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 5
            rectangle5 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[5]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[5])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[5] == "red"){
                        kaarten[5] = "yellow";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="3";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 5;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 6
            rectangle6 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[6]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[6])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[6] == "red"){
                        kaarten[6] = "yellow";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="3";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 6;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 7
            rectangle7 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[7]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[7])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[7] == "red"){
                        kaarten[7] = "purple";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="4";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 7;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 8
            rectangle8 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[8]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 70
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[8])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[8] == "red"){
                        kaarten[8] = "purple";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="4";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 8;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 9
            rectangle9 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[9]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[9])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[9] == "red"){
                        kaarten[9] = "grey";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="5";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 9;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 10
            rectangle10 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[10]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[10])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[10] == "red"){
                        kaarten[10] = "grey";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="5";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 10;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 11
            rectangle11 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[11]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[11])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[11] == "red"){
                        kaarten[11] = "magenta";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="6";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 11;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 12
            rectangle12 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[12]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 130
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[12])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[12] == "red"){
                        kaarten[12] = "magenta";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="6";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 12;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 13
            rectangle13 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[13]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 50
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[13])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[13] == "red"){
                        kaarten[13] = "orange";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="7";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 13;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 14
            rectangle14 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[14]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 110
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[14])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[14] == "red"){
                        kaarten[14] = "orange";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="7";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 14;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 15
            rectangle15 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[15]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 170
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[15])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[15] == "red"){
                        kaarten[15] = "blue";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="8";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 15;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
            //Kaart 16
            rectangle16 = Rectangle {
                visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[16]
                width: 50
                height: 50
                x: 190
                y: 230
                arcWidth: 10
                arcHeight: 10
                fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[16])
                onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                    if (kaarten[16] == "red"){
                        kaarten[16] = "blue";
                        kaartkeuze[aantalclicks]="8";
                        gekozenkaart[aantalclicks]= 16;
                        aantalclicks ++;
                        KaartControle()
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import java.util.Random;

def colors = [
    Color.web("#d02020"),
    Color.web("#ff8010"),
    Color.web("#d0e000"),
    Color.web("#10c010"),
    Color.web("#3030f0"),
    Color.web("#d050ff"),
];

def rand = new Random();   
function randColor():Color {
    colors[rand.nextInt(sizeof colors)]
}
```

Source Material: http://www.smarks.org/svjugfx20100414/flood.html

-Update-

Random Colors:

```
function getColor(): Integer
    {
        var c:java.awt.Color = new java.awt.Color(
            Math.random() * 255,
            Math.random() * 255,
            Math.random() * 255);

        return
        c.getRGB();
    }
```

This function gets a random rgb value which you can use in the fill. This means you don't require an array of colors if you don't want.

Source Material: http://codersimperative.blogspot.com/2009/01/creating-custom-fill-in-javafx.html

Comment: okay, but what do i do with the fill of eacht rectangle in the rest of the code?

Comment: oh and where do i put the def colors, def rand en function? in my function or in the stage? or none of these?

Comment: That's correct :) The top code will do everything you need, just think about it for a sec. The updated code is only if you need a totally random color which it doesn't seem like it from your sample code. I added it anyway just in case.

Comment: oh okay, then i will use the first one

Comment: the only problem, they all got black

Comment: they are still all black now when i click on them

Comment: You need to make sure that you call a new random each time. Think of it this way. A random color is an object, you need to make sure you are creating a new color object each time. If you are reusing the same color object, the color will always be the same. Check out section 5 of the first link.

Comment: In that example the random color is created with each new rectangle. Try calling it from within your rectangle constructor.

Comment: sorry i don't understand, i'm kinda bad at javafx, only using it for a few weeks now

Comment: It's ok, this isn't a simple thing to do. You are doing very well. It will be hard form to troubleshoot like this so I can only give you hints from here. My advice for you to try...

Comment: Each rectangle has two states. Covered which is the same for all, and the color hidden. When you create your rectangle you need to generate a random color and save that. You display the covered color and onclick, change the fill of the rectangle to the random color. You can then reset it and still have the color saved in a variable for that rectangles object.

Comment: I would do this. Create a new project with a single rectangle. When you create the rectangle call the random color and save it to a color variable. Set the fill to your covered color. Onclick, change the fill to your random color. If you can get this to work, all you have to do is apply it back to your code.

Comment: pfff, okey, i'm going to get myself some snacks and drinks and then i'm going to try haha, thank you

Comment: As for the colors, you have a solution in your original work. You defined an array of colors. What if you had a "var" array of colors? You could directly reference an index to get or set a color at will. So then rectangle1 might be associated with index 0, rectangle2 with index 1, etc... This link has a color array, I wouldn't do it just like this, but this should give you the idea http://code-better.com/javafx/color-constants-demo

Comment: so i should use the def colors to choose 8 colors, but how do i randomize and make sure it is still the same color when i click te card again? And what do you mean by index?

Comment: I think I know where you are sticking conceptually. The concept of an array is like this. An array is a container that you put things in. You access the stuff you put in by what is called an index. If I have an array of 5 colors and I put them in an array like yellow, red, blue, green, purple they will stay in there will the program executes. Lets say I want to access a color in the array, I refrence a colors by an index. An index  is a number that represents a colors place in an array. In our example lets say I want to access color green, it is the 4th color...

Comment: Therefore it is at the index 4-1=3. I subtract 1 because computers start their indices at 0 instead of 1. So if I want yellow it is at index 0, purple is at index 4. So our rectangles on have to keep a number...this number is the index where their stored color is at in the array. Remember we want to set the colors as we execute the application, so the array should be a "var" not "def"

Comment: Check out  this tutorial on arrays http://nikojava.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/javafx-script-for-java-developers-part-2/

Comment: Hey monkeydoug, the code is much better now, it is random each time but there is still a little problem, colors can be more than 2 times, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, import does work, but they al keep getting black, not a random color and i still don't know how to save te random color, my code, with one card because they are all the same except for card numbers enz is:

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.util.Random;

def colors = [
    Color.web("#d0e000"),
    Color.web("#d02020"),
    Color.web("#ff8010"),
    Color.web("#10c010"),
    Color.web("#3030f0"),
    Color.web("#d050ff"),
];

def rand = new Random();

function randColor():Color {
    colors[rand.nextInt(sizeof colors)]
}

var rectangle1: Rectangle;
var rectangle2: Rectangle;
var rectangle3: Rectangle;
var rectangle4: Rectangle;
var rectangle5: Rectangle;
var rectangle6: Rectangle;
var rectangle7: Rectangle;
var rectangle8: Rectangle;
var rectangle9: Rectangle;
var rectangle10: Rectangle;
var rectangle11: Rectangle;
var rectangle12: Rectangle;
var rectangle13: Rectangle;
var rectangle14: Rectangle;
var rectangle15: Rectangle;
var rectangle16: Rectangle;
var kaarten = ["", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red",];
var kaartzichtbaar = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
var gekozenkaart = [0, 0, 0];
var tekst = "beginnen maar";
var aantalclicks = 0;
var kaartkeuze = ["", ""];
var scene: Scene;
var button: Button;
var score = 0;

function KaartControle() { if (aantalclicks == 2) { if (kaartkeuze[0] == kaartkeuze[1]) { tekst = "goed bezig!"; kaartzichtbaar[gekozenkaart[0]] = false; kaartzichtbaar[gekozenkaart[1]] = false; aantalclicks = 0; score++; } } else if (aantalclicks == 3) { tekst = "jammer!"; kaarten[gekozenkaart[0]] = "red"; kaarten[gekozenkaart[1]] = "red"; kaarten[gekozenkaart[2]] = "red"; aantalclicks = 0; score--; } if (score == 8) { tekst = "Hoera!! Het spel is voltooid"; } }

Stage {
    title: "Memory"
    scene: Scene {
        width: 500
        height: 300
        content: [
            Text {
                font: Font {
                    size: 16
                }
                x: 10
                y: 30
                content: bind tekst;
            }
            Text {
                font: Font {
                    size: 16
                }
                x: 250
                y: 30
                content: bind score.toString();
            }
            button = Button {
                        translateX: 300
                        translateY: 150
                        text: "reset"
                        visible: true
                        action: function() {
                            kaartzichtbaar = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
                            kaarten = ["", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red",];
                            aantalclicks = 0;
                            score = 0;
                        }
                    }

            //Kaart 1
            rectangle1 = Rectangle {
                        visible: bind kaartzichtbaar[1]
                        width: 50
                        height: 50
                        x: 10
                        y: 50
                        arcWidth: 10
                        arcHeight: 10
                        fill: bind Color.web(kaarten[1])
                        onMouseClicked: function(event) {
                            if (kaarten[1] == "red") {
                                kaarten[1] = "randColor()";
                                kaartkeuze[aantalclicks] = "1";
                                gekozenkaart[aantalclicks] = 1;
                                aantalclicks++;
                                KaartControle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
```